# How to debug a bad Cocoa binding?

Tags: swift, cocoa-bindings

I'm converting some code from using IBOutlets to Cocoa bindings. The screen is very simple:

[image]

The declarations in my Swift class are:

```
class UnitsVC : NSViewController {
    private var deck: Deck?

    dynamic var CurrentUnits: String = "Meters"
    dynamic var CurrentScale: Double = 1.0
    dynamic var NewUnits: String = "Meters"
    dynamic var NewScale:  Double = 1.0
    dynamic var Scale:  Double = 1.0

    dynamic var ChangeDimensions: Bool = true
    dynamic var ChangeDiameters: Bool = true
    dynamic var ChangeUnitsToBase: Bool = false
```

But when I display the screen, I get:

```
2016-04-08 08:39:31.563 SwiftNEC[73176:5317145] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-04-08 08:39:31.563 SwiftNEC[73176:5317145] Cannot create BOOL from object <SwiftNEC.UnitsVC: 0x618000164ec0> of class SwiftNEC.UnitsVC
2016-04-08 08:39:31.567 SwiftNEC[73176:5317145] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff93e044f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8a91673c objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff93e091ca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff949b65a4 _NSHandleBindingException + 302
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff943f583e _NSBoolFromValue + 386
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff94492a4b -[_NSCheckBoxPlugin showValue:inObject:] + 71
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff942d0b18 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 463
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff942d08b9 -[NSValueBinder _observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:context:] + 296
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff94221865 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 758
```

So apparently one of the check boxes is wired improperly. But which one? There seems to be nothing in the bindings that appears to be wrong. I bind to the Value of each of the boxes, and checking in both the bindings and the connections I can't see anything else:

[image]

I even tried removing all the bindings I could see, but I still get the same problem.

So, how do I debug this? It doesn't appear anything useful is spit out in the debugger output, notably the key, which would indicate the problem. Is there some way to get this information?

Comment: Remove `self`, that's not needed. And – although it doesn't affect the issue –  follow the naming convention to name variables with a starting lowercase letter

Comment: Set the NSBindingDebugLogLevel preference to 1.

Comment: Select UnitsVC, go to the Connections Inspector and check the bindings.

Comment: I did, I mentioned that in the original post.